# SCSS image path not working

Tags: html, css, sass

Okay so let's assume, for simplicity's sake that my folder structure looks like this:

```
project
   - index.html
   - css
      - style.css
      - scss
         - style.scss
   - img
      - image.jpg
```

I want to use my **image.jpg** as a background for a div. I am working from **style.scss** and then monitoring the scss to css in **style.css**. If I use the path **../../img/image.jpg** it will be displayed as correct in **style.scss**, but since I am monitoring this to **style.css**, the image will not be displayed because the path to the image from **style.css** is **../img/image.jpg**. This goes both ways, If I use the path **../img/image.jpg** the image should not be displayed because the path is incorrect for **style.scss**. How can I make this work?

Comment: Put both `css` and `scss` file in same folder

Comment: Seems it is about transpiler settings/definitions. Do you use external transpiler (scss to css) or some IDE?

Comment: @DicBrus I use Webstorm IDE to write my code.

Comment: @Bhuwan Well I have to use a certain file structure so I cant just put them all in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personnally set the images url to fit the `style.css` needs.

In my point of view, `style.scss` is here only to provide more flexibility during the coding of your design. This way, i never use `.scss` files inside my HTML.

Taking the in mind that i always compile the `.scss` into `.css`, that makes no sense to me to set the path from the `.scss` file.

By the way, i know there are tools allowing to auto-compile `.scss` files before returning them compile from the server, but i'm not pretty fan of this solution, because more than requesting a file in HTTP GET, you'll need your server to compile code before returning it, so it'll obviously take a bit more time...

Comment: in your method you miss auto-complete that provided by WebStorm. You should remember/copy-paste/type-without-mistakes the names of image files

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions for that to use absolute path to your images, I mean, like:
`/img/image.jpg`

therefore you will still have autocomplete in IDE 
and css will be transpiled correctly